# Run function on gradle build and save result as JSON in resources

Tags: android, gradle

So I have an activity in Android that accesses a class with a static function that generates a static two-dimensional double array. Generating this array takes a while, and it will lagg the app for several minutes. But the resulting array is always the same.

My idea was to make some sort of gradle script that runs when building the app. This script then runs the static function of the class, this generates the two-dimensional double array. I convert this array to json and save it to the resource files. When the app is used it gets the json file and converts it back into the static two-dimensional double array. This removes the need of running the function and cuts down loading time.

I am not sure if I'm tackling this problem the right way. The function that generates the array has several static parameters that I want to finetune. How should I proceed, because I have searched but did not find a suitable answer. Thank you in advance!

---

This topic explains how to generate a JSON file with Gradle. [Custom Gradle Task to save parsed Json to file. Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934371/custom-gradle-task-to-save-parsed-json-to-file-android)
But I have not found a way to access the function from gradle. I don't know if it is even possible.